# How to return a cell value if the date in a range of cells is today in google sheets

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets

I currently have a Google Sheet, with numerous sheets in it, to track contract deadlines for different clients. One of these sheets shows me all of the deadlines in Columns E:M for every contract. Each row is a separate contract.

I'm trying to create a separate sheet that will show me the client's name, found in column A, if a date in columns E:M is Today. That way I can look at one page and see all the clients that have a deadline today. Here is what I tried with no success:

```
=if('U/C(Dont Edit)'E2:M2=TODAY(),'U/C(Dont Edit)'A2,"")
```

"U/C(Dont Edit)" is the sheet that shows all of the contracts.

I believe the problem lies when I try to apply "=Today()" to a range(E:M). It seems to work fine if I just use E2=Today(). It looks like I could accomplish my goal using If statements within If statements, but that gets very messy very quickly and I'm hoping there is a better way.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `COUNTIF()` function per row:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E2:M2,TODAY())>0,A2,"")
```

But I think a better solution is to use the `FILTER()` function. It will give you a list of names:

```
=FILTER(A2:A,(E2:E=TODAY())+(F2:F=TODAY())+(G2:G=TODAY())+(H2:H=TODAY())+
 (I2:I=TODAY())+(J2:J=TODAY())+(K2:K=TODAY())+(L2:L=TODAY())+(M2:M=TODAY()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest @dePatinkin's solution (for and additional column, say N, containing the COUNTIF formula from Row2 downwards) in combination with a query (in another sheet):

```
=query('U/C(Dont Edit)'!A:N,"select * where N is not NULL")
```

This assumes your existing sheet has the columns labelled.

You might combine the above with [Conditional formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402907/change-the-background-of-one-google-sheets-column-based-on-the-date-in-another-c) to indicate which column has the date in it (today) that triggered the row selection.